The percolation threshold of my function creating a path from bottom to top is 0.1 too high
My goal is to compute an approximate value of the percolation threshold of a path from top to bottom in a matrix containing black and white cells. To do this, I randomly blacken cells and, after each step, I detect if there is a path made of black cells going from any top cell (first row) to any cell at the bottom (last row) of the matrix (without diagonal jumps). If so, the percolation will be reached. The percolation threshold is the proportion of black cells that it is probabilistically necessary to blacken to reach the percolation. This threshold is the same for any matrix that is not too small.
To represent a square matrix M of size N, I use a one-dimensional array T of size NxN : the cell in the row i and column j in M (with i and j between 0 and N-1) corresponds to the element of index i.N + j in T.
My problem is that my percolation threshold lies around 0.7, while it should be 0.6 normally. I tried to find the errors in my code but everything seems to be fine and I cannot find my mistake. Here is the code I created :
public class Percolation {
    public static final int size = 10;
    public static final int length = size * size;
    public static boolean[] grid = new boolean[length];

    public static void init() {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            grid[i] = false;
        }
    }

    public static void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                int index = i * size + j;
                if (grid[index]) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("-");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static int randomShadow() {
        int index;
        do {
            index = (int) (Math.random() * length);
        } while (grid[index]);
        grid[index] = true; 
        return index;
    }


    public static boolean isNaivePercolation(int n) {
        boolean[] seen = new boolean[length];
        
        
        boolean pathToTop = detectPath(seen, n, true);
        
        boolean pathToBottom = detectPath(seen, n, false);
        
        // Percolation occurs if there's a path to both top and bottom rows
        return pathToTop && pathToBottom;
    }

    private static boolean detectPath(boolean[] seen, int n, boolean up) {
        if (n < 0 || n >= length || seen[n] || !grid[n]) {
            return false; // Out of bounds, already visited cell, or white cell
        }
        if ((up && n < size) || (!up && n >= length - size)) {
            return true; // Reached top or bottom row
        }
        seen[n] = true; // Mark cell as visited
        int row = n / size;
        int col = n % size;
        // Check neighboring cells (up, down, left, right)
        return detectPath(seen, n - size, up) ||
               detectPath(seen, n + size, up) ||
               (col > 0 && detectPath(seen, n - 1, up)) ||
               (col < size - 1 && detectPath(seen, n + 1, up));
    }

    public static boolean isPercolation(int n) {
        return isNaivePercolation(n);
    }

    public static double percolation() {
        init(); // Initialize the matrix
        int blackenedCells = 0;
        int index;
        boolean percolationDetected = false;
        while (!percolationDetected) {
            index = randomShadow(); // Blacken a random white cell
            blackenedCells++;
            percolationDetected = isPercolation(index);
        }
        print();
        return (double) blackenedCells / length; // Return the proportion of blackened cells
    }
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        init();
        System.out.println("Matrix after initializing:");
        print();
        System.out.println();

        int blackenedIndex = randomShadow();
        System.out.println("Matrix after blackening a random cell:");
        print();
        System.out.println("Index of blackened cell: " + blackenedIndex);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Testing percolation:");
        double percolationThreshold = percolation();
        System.out.println("Percolation threshold: " + percolationThreshold);
    }
}

I have tried to debug multiple times, do examples by hand, copilot.

Sample size perhaps, try with larger size, say 100 and more runs

Your code implements the method isNaivePercolation(int n) such that it indicates the occurrence of percolation.
However, in percolation simulations it is important that one can move from the top corner all the way down. You only need to find a path to the bottom.
One way to solve this would be the following:
public static boolean isPercolation() {
    boolean[] visited = new boolean[length];
    for (int start = 0; start < size; start++) {
        if (grid[start]) {  
            if (detectPath(visited, start, false)) { 
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

and also call isPercolation without the index parameter.
public static double percolation() {
        init(); // Initialize the matrix
        int blackenedCells = 0;
        int index;
        boolean percolationDetected = false;
        while (!percolationDetected) {
            index = randomShadow(); // Blacken a random white cell
            blackenedCells++;
            percolationDetected = isPercolation(); // <---
        }
        print();
        return (double) blackenedCells / length; // Return the proportion of blackened cells
}


Given that this looks like coursework, I'll just give you hints not an answer.
Clearly any statistics aren't going to be a close match to 0.6 unless you run many times and with larger data sets. If you run several times with size = 2 you would expect to see results of only 0.5 and 0.75.
You have a logic error, just test with size = 2. Occasionally it will report incorrect result 1.0:
Testing percolation:
**
**
Percolation threshold: 1.0

You will also find the loop never exits sometimes, add a test inside percolation() to spot when all cells are full:
while (!percolationDetected) {
    // VALIDATE THE isPercolation() call works:
    if (blackenedCells == length) {
        print();
        throw new RuntimeException("There is a bug, page of cells is FULL");
    }
    index = randomShadow(); // Blacken a random white cell
    blackenedCells++;
    percolationDetected = isPercolation(index);
}

You can make it easier to use and test your application if you eliminate all the static methods and member fields and then you can instantiate many independent instances of Percolation and perform many runs with just:
DoubleSummaryStatistics runs = IntStream.range(5, 150)
                               .parallel()
                               .mapToObj(i -> new Percolation(i))
                               .mapToDouble(Percolation::percolation)
                               .summaryStatistics();
System.out.println("Test runs:"+ runs.getCount()+" average perc:"+runs.getAverage());

